# strange ? symbol in mysql post

Tags: php, mysql, web

Whenever I put `ñ` in a mysql row... it `$_POST`'s it as a strange triangular ? symbol...

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Do you use proper encoding on the server/client and database side?

Comment: set proper page encoding with `Content-type` HTTP header.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to check if your mysql column is has the correct encoding (utf8 probably).

Then you may need to enable utf8 when connecting to mysql, at least that's what I must do in Perl.

This link might help http://dreweyscorner.blogspot.com/2008/01/enable-utf-8-on-php-mysql-and-apache.html

Answer (score -1):

It's a mismatch between the encoding used to store the accented character in the database and the charset used by the page that displays it. The text was probably stored as ISO-8859-1 (Western European), but is being displayed as Unicode (UTF-8).

Make sure that the insert form and the display page both use the same encoding. These days, both should have the following  tag in the  of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Unless you're using an obsolete version of MySQL (such as 3.23), it should support UTF-8 encoding by default.